disable caching of DNS names for ProxyPass remote server
I have the equivalent of the two configuration entries, to serve a client request by retrieving the required info from another host in the local network.
The used hostname is acually a CNAME of some machine. This week this machine died, and I changed the CNAME to point to another machine in the local network.
However, even after a day or two Apache tried to contact the IP of the dead machine. I expected that it would cache the DNS query result for a short time (seconds or minutes), and then query it again. But that did not happen, only a systemctl restart apache2 fixed it. Now i resolves the name properly.
Any idea if there is a way to influence the way how long IP for resolved hostnames are cached? The TTL in DNS for this zone is short (SOA is N 123m 1m 5d 10m).
ProxyPass        "/some/path" "http://hostname/some/path"
ProxyPassReverse "/some/path" "http://hostname/some/path"



What TTL do you have for the individual records? The SOA TTL is only the minimum TTL, as well as the 'negative result' TTL; positive results are cached for their individual record TTLs.

The documentation of mod_proxy shows two options which affect DNS caching: disablereuse=On or enablereuse=Off, and addressttl=123.
It seems the latter is what should help with changing DNS entries.
As a result, the config above should look like this:
ProxyPass        "/some/path" "http://hostname/some/path" addressttl=123
ProxyPassReverse "/some/path" "http://hostname/some/path" addressttl=123

